# Resharper intellisense : how to show method return type

Tags: methods, resharper, intellisense

I've formatted my pc, and now i can't seem to find the option to show the method return type in the intellisense...

Using VS 2015 RC with Resharper 9.1.1

Thanks, screenshot below.

[image: intellisense]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the corresponding setting:
[image: R# Options]